# Linear map of finite or infinite extreme points. Discuss injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, convex-polytopes, convex-analysis

Before entering my problem, let me review some related results:

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a  convex hull of finite points: $\mathcal{S}=\operatorname{conv}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$, then

1. By "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282036/convex-hull-of-extreme-points" , we know $\mathcal{S}$ is the convex hull of its extreme points, which is the subset of $\{x_1,\ldots, x_m\}$.
2. By "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591561/preservation-of-extreme-points-under-linear-transformation", if the transformation is linear, let $A$ = {the extreme points of the image of a compact convex set}, then the **preimage** of $A$ must be the extreme points of that compact convex set. But the **inverse** in not true. The inverse is true only under such transformation 
   is injective and surjective.

My question is:

Suppose

1. We have two sets $A,B$ with $L: A\rightarrow B$, which is **linear**.
2. $A,B$ are both convex hull of finite extreme points, compact and both sets have at least one extreme point.
3. Suppose $L$ maps **extreme points** in $A$ **one-to-one and onto** to **extreme points** in $B$.

Question: Is $L$ a one-to-one and onto linear map for $A\rightarrow B$?

If not, could you please provide an counter-example?

---

Moreover, if $A,B$ are convex hull of **infinite extreme points**, will I get the same answer?

This part comes from an example:

The extreme points of $A$ can be $SO(2)$ 
, i.e. a set of  $2×2$  rotation matrices with $0≤θ≤2π$, to make an one-to-one map. The extreme points of $B$  is a set of rank one, $2×2$ positive semidefinite matrices with trace one. So $B$ 
 can be built by $vv^T$  where $v = [v_1 v_2]^T$
 with $v_1^2 +v_2^2 =1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you should try to map the vertices of a tetrahedron linearly onto the vertices of a square.  For example by a projection $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I see. It is surjective but not injective in your example and this is for finite extreme points. Therefore it is not injective for the case of infinite extreme points certainly.